# Azure AD logout - Close browser to finish signing out - uncaught referenceError

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, electron, jquery-plugins, azure-ad-msal

My current project is built on .NET Core 6 + Reactjs (ver - 16.13.0) + ElctronNet (Electron - ver 26). It is a desktop application.

I'm implementing Microsoft login in our application in order to access the One drive storage. The component that is used is react-microsoft-login. The application is able to login properly, get the microsoft token and access the One Drive information. However, I have issue when logout the account. It shows the below info and redirect immediately to the main page. If I click the 'head back to localhost' it will redirect to the main page and account is logout.

[image]

From the console I get this issue, when the above page is displayed:

[image]

In our application we set the NodeIntegration: true as we need the access to the ipcRenderer. I noticed that the application is able to logout properly if the NodeIntegration is set to false. However, I need it to be true so that my existing functions work.

I've stuck for some time on this issue. Is there a way to keep the NodeIntegration: true, and logout properly?